# How to setup Keycloak with a postgres database in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I am currently trying to setup keycloak with a postgres database on minikube. The problem is that keycloak cant connect to my postgres db and ends in a crashloopbackerror.

Here my configuration:

Postgres-deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-volume-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Mi
status: {}

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-database
  labels:
    app: postgres-database
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: postgres-database
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: postgres-database
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: postgres-database
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-secret
              key: postgres-database
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-secret
              key: postgres-password
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-secret
              key: postgres-username
        image: postgres
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5431
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
          name: postgres-storage
      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: postgres-volume-claim
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: postgres-database
  name: postgres-keycloak
spec:
  ports:
    - name: postgres-keycloak
      port: 5431
      targetPort: 5431
  selector:
    app: postgres-database
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

keycloak-deyployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    io.kompose.service: keycloak
  name: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      io.kompose.service: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: postgres-keycloak
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-secret
              key: postgres-database
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-secret
              key: postgres-password
        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-secret
              key: postgres-username
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: POSTGRES
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-secret
              key: keycloak-password
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-secret
              key: keycloak-username
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.1
        imagePullPolicy: ""
        name: keycloak
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
        resources: {}
      restartPolicy: Always
      serviceAccountName: ""
      volumes: null
```

Keycloak-service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak
spec:
  ports:
  - name: "8443"
    port: 8443
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    io.kompose.service: keycloak
  type: NodePort
```

kubectl get all

```
NAME                                     READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
pod/keycloak-84fd96bbbf-wmpgt            0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   5          8m14s
pod/postgres-database-6467d78d5d-b6pj9   1/1     Running            0          8m13s

NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
service/keycloak            NodePort    10.98.180.162    <none>        8443:31882/TCP   8m13s
service/kubernetes          ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP          8m36s
service/postgres-keycloak   ClusterIP   10.100.233.109   <none>        5431/TCP         8m13s

NAME                                READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/keycloak            0/1     1            0           8m14s
deployment.apps/postgres-database   1/1     1            1           8m13s

NAME                                           DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/keycloak-84fd96bbbf            1         1         0       8m14s
replicaset.apps/postgres-database-6467d78d5d   1         1         1       8m13s
```

and the error when running kubectl logs keycloak

```
23:27:43,693 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYCLINF0002: Started authorizationRevisions cache from keycloak container
23:27:43,714 INFO  [org.keycloak.connections.infinispan.DefaultInfinispanConnectionProviderFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) Node name: keycloak-84fd96bbbf-wmpgt, Site name: null
23:27:54,349 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) IJ000604: Throwable while attempting to get a new connection: null: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1326)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getSimpleConnection(AbstractPool.java:632)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:604)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:151)
        at org.jboss.as.connector@19.1.0.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.WildFlyDataSource.getConnection(WildFlyDataSource.java:64)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@10.0.1//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.getConnection(DefaultJpaConnectionProviderFactory.java:371)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@10.0.1//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lazyInit(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:65)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@10.0.1//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.lambda$waitForLock$2(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:96)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@10.0.1//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.suspendJtaTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:682)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-model-jpa@10.0.1//org.keycloak.connections.jpa.updater.liquibase.lock.LiquibaseDBLockProvider.waitForLock(LiquibaseDBLockProvider.java:94)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication$1.run(KeycloakApplication.java:145)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-server-spi-private@10.0.1//org.keycloak.models.utils.KeycloakModelUtils.runJobInTransaction(KeycloakModelUtils.java:227)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.startup(KeycloakApplication.java:138)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-wildfly-extensions@10.0.1//org.keycloak.provider.wildfly.WildflyPlatform.onStartup(WildflyPlatform.java:29)
        at org.keycloak.keycloak-services@10.0.1//org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication.<init>(KeycloakApplication.java:125)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.core.ConstructorInjectorImpl.construct(ConstructorInjectorImpl.java:152)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyProviderFactory.createProviderInstance(ResteasyProviderFactory.java:2805)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.createApplication(ResteasyDeployment.java:369)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.startInternal(ResteasyDeployment.java:281)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:92)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.init(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:119)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs@3.11.2.Final//org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.init(HttpServletDispatcher.java:36)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:117)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.init(RunAsLifecycleInterceptor.java:78)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.proceed(LifecyleInterceptorInvocation.java:103)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:305)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:145)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:585)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$2.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:556)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1541)
        at io.undertow.servlet@2.1.0.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:598)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:97)
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:78)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
        at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.20.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
        ... 57 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
        at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242)
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:403)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
        ... 62 more

23:27:54,357 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
23:27:54,359 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Thread-1) WFLYSRV0220: Server shutdown has been requested via an OS signal
23:27:54,359 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,361 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.ThemeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,361 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakSecurityHeadersFilter from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,362 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.filters.KeycloakTransactionCommitter from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,362 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002205: Adding provider class org.keycloak.services.error.KeycloakErrorHandler from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,362 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002200: Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.JsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,362 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002210: Adding provider singleton org.keycloak.services.util.ObjectMapperResolver from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,362 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RobotsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,363 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.WelcomeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,363 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RealmsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,363 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY002220: Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminRoot from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
23:27:54,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/KeycloakDS]
23:27:54,396 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
23:27:54,398 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
23:27:54,401 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
23:27:54,402 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYMAIL0002: Unbound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
23:27:54,420 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTPS listener https suspending
23:27:54,430 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTPS listener https stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8443
23:27:54,430 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = postgresql
23:27:54,439 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.18.Final
23:27:54,457 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.validation.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) RESTEASY008550: Unable to find CDI supporting ValidatorFactory. Using default ValidatorFactory
23:27:54,631 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/auth' for server 'default-server'
23:27:54,633 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/auth' from server 'default-server'
23:27:54,638 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) MODCLUSTER000002: Initiating mod_cluster shutdown
23:27:54,638 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0008: Undertow AJP listener ajp suspending
23:27:54,639 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0007: Undertow AJP listener ajp stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8009
23:27:54,641 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0010: Unbound data source [java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS]
23:27:54,643 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = h2
23:27:54,652 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYUT0019: Host default-host stopping
23:27:54,657 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0008: Undertow HTTP listener default suspending
23:27:54,659 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0007: Undertow HTTP listener default stopped, was bound to 0.0.0.0:8080
23:27:54,659 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 65) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped client-mappings cache from ejb container
23:27:54,660 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped users cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,659 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped realms cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,659 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped keys cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authorization cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,662 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0004: Undertow 2.1.0.Final stopping
23:27:54,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment keycloak-server.war (runtime-name: keycloak-server.war) in 309ms
23:27:54,679 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped loginFailures cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,680 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped sessions cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,681 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped offlineClientSessions cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,682 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped offlineSessions cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,683 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 68) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped clientSessions cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,684 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 67) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped authenticationSessions cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,685 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped actionTokens cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,715 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYCLINF0003: Stopped work cache from keycloak container
23:27:54,715 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-1) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
23:27:54,731 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000080: Disconnecting JGroups channel ejb
23:27:54,760 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "microprofile-metrics-smallrye")]): java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics-smallrye@19.1.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.microprofile.metrics.MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd$2.execute(MicroProfileMetricsSubsystemAdd.java:86)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:999)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:467)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1413)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.boot(ModelControllerImpl.java:527)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:515)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService.boot(AbstractControllerService.java:477)
        at org.jboss.as.server@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:448)
        at org.jboss.as.server@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.server.ServerService.boot(ServerService.java:401)
        at org.jboss.as.controller@11.1.1.Final//org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractControllerService$1.run(AbstractControllerService.java:416)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was: my problem was that my DB wasnt starting. The reason was that my VM didnt have enough memory to fullfill the PVC.

Comment: i have similar error while using keycloak with postgres DB. but not able to resolve. error: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "keycloak"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:514)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:141)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)

Comment: I am also trying to deploy keycloak with postgresql(AWS RDS instance) and it is failing with below error:

ERROR: Failed to start server in (production) mode
2022-06-23 16:40:14,895 ERROR (main) ERROR: Failed to obtain JDBC connection
2022-06-23 16:40:14,895 ERROR  (main) ERROR: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://kc.****.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/keycloakdb

deployment file: keycloak deploy - Pastebin.com

Answer (score 4):

You can please this out files

i have tested and working for me  https://github.com/harsh4870/Keycloack-postgres-kubernetes-deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak
  namespace: default
  labels:
    app: keycloak
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak
        image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:10.0.0
        env:
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          value: "admin"
        - name: PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING
          value: "true"
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: POSTGRES
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: postgres
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: keycloak
        - name: DB_USER
          value: root
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          value: password
        - name : KEYCLOAK_HTTP_PORT
          value : "80"
        - name: KEYCLOAK_HTTPS_PORT
          value: "443"
        - name : KEYCLOAK_HOSTNAME
          value : keycloak.harshmanvar.tk #replace with ingress URL
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 8080
        - name: https
          containerPort: 8443
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /auth/realms/master
            port: 8080
```

Comment: Thanks for the input i tried it out with your configuration but it doesnt semm to work. I am getting the same error as before. I updated my minikube because i thought it might be a version conflict but that didnt change anything. When i rund kubectl describe pods i see the following problem in the postgres pod:  0/1 nodes are available: 1 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.

Comment: your DB is not up please check there is issue of PVC and minikube.