# cannot connect keycloak container to postgres container in kubernetes

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, keycloak

this is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: keycloak-postgres-deployment-client1
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: keycloak-postgres-client1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: keycloak-postgres-client1
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: keycloak-client1
        image: jboss/keycloak
        env:
        - name: DB_VENDOR
          value: POSTGRES
        - name: DB_ADDR
          value: postgres-client1
        - name: DB_PORT
          value: "5432"
        - name: DB_DATABASE
          value: keycloak-client1
        - name: DB_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-credentials-client1
              key: client_db_username
        - name: DB_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-credentials-client1
              key: client_db_password
        - name: KEYCLOAK_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-credentials-client1
              key: client_kc_username
        - name: KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: keycloak-credentials-client1
              key: client_kc_password
        - name: KC_PROXY
          value: "edge"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: http
        - containerPort: 8443
          name: https
      - name: postgres-client1
        image: postgres:latest
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_DB
          value: keycloak-client1
        - name: POSTGRES_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-credentials-client1
              key: client_db_username
        - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: postgres-credentials-client1
              key: client_db_password
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5432
          name: postgres
        volumeMounts:
        - name: postgres-data-client1
          mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
      volumes:
      - name: postgres-data-client1
        emptyDir:
          sizeLimit: 500Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: keycloak-service-client1
  labels:
    app: keycloak-client1
spec:
  selector:
    app: keycloak-client1
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    targetPort: 8080
  - name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8443
```

And this is the error i get from the pod:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256)
        at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.5.3.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:335)
        ... 60 more
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-client1
        at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:229)
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc@42.2.5//org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192)
        ... 65 more

13:09:05,875 FATAL [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) Error during startup: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to connect to database
```

So i thought that the name of DB_ADDR in the env of keycloak should match the name of the container running postgres in order to keycloak to find postgres, but apparently that is not the case.

Comment: Apparently changing DB_ADDR to localhost solved this. Now i have the problem that keycloak is not exposed by the service (so the service says it does not have any endpoints or pods), anyone that have a guess of why is this the case? in the yaml file i used the selector field to specify to the service the keycloak container

Answer (score 0):

**DB_ADDR** will be the IP of the **Postgres** running or **Service** **name** of **Postgress** database.

You can refer my Github files : https://github.com/harsh4870/Keycloack-postgres-kubernetes-deployment/blob/main/keycload-deployment.yaml

i have used the **Postgress** & **Keycloak** setup

Also refer to my other answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66576248/5525824